# What is the point of [START functionsimport] and similar comments in Firebase examples?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

See here for example:

https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/quickstarts/time-server/functions/index.js

Do these comments have an effect on the logging output or is this some kind of automatic docs generator like AsciiDoc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are just used to determine which code samples should be embedded in product documentation.  They have no meaning otherwise.

Compare your given link with https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events